# How to position these numbers around a clock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, trigonometry

Evidentially my trig is a bit rusty. How can I get the minutes to wrap around the clock?

[codepen](http://codepen.io/mnbayazit/pen/mFokd) [**update:** forgot codepen isn't versioned like jsfiddle; this 'pen' is a work in progress and no longer represents the problem I had at the time of this question]

Javascript:

```
var r = $('.face').width()/2;
var j = r-18;
for(var min=0; min<60; min += 5) {
  var str = min < 10 ? '0'+min : String(min);
  var x = j*Math.sin(Math.PI*2*(min/60));
  var y = j*Math.cos(Math.PI*2*(min/60));
  console.log(x);
  $('<div>',{'class':'time'})
    .text(str)
    .css({
      marginLeft: (x+r-12)+'px',
      marginTop: (-y+r-12)+'px'
    })
    .appendTo('.face');
}
```

Comment: Turns out your trig is fine.

Comment: Incidentally, you can simplify `Math.PI*2*(min/60)` to `Math.PI*min/30`, or even just `min*0.10472`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All your `.time` divs are below one another. Give the `.time` class absolute positioning.

Comment: +1 for being the only correct answer. I'd give another one for being the only one not to assume the math is wrong without reading through it.

Comment: Hah! I was messing with the CSS and must have removed that. Thanks for catching my silly mistake :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming min is between 0-60, and bearing in mind that there are 360 degrees in a circle:

```
var degToMin = 360/60; // 6
var minDeg = min * degToMin; // this will tell us how many degrees around the circle the minutes are
var minRad = minDeg * (Math.PI/180); // convert to radians
var x = j*Math.cos(minRad); // cos is the x coord, while sin is the y coord
var y = j*Math.sin(minRad);
```

Comment: OP already dealt with this: `Math.PI*2*(min/60)`. Degrees don't come into this.

Comment: This is true, but I prefer less complicated code, especially in examples, as it's easier to understand. The main problem I think is mixing up cos and sin.

Comment: No, the code has the trig functions in the correct order, since it's going clockwise from the top, rather than the regular direction of angle measure.

Answer (score 0):

Going from `0` to `360` degrees (`0` to `2 pi` radians) normally starts at 3 o'clock, and goes counterclockwise.

So we need to reverse the direction so that it goes clockwise, and rotate it counterclockwise 90 degrees (`pi/2` radians) so that it starts at 12 o'clock.

Each hour runs through `pi/6` radians, so the position at hour `h` would be:

```
x = x_c + r cos (-h*pi/6 + pi/2)
y = y_c + r sin (-h*pi/6 + pi/2)
```

where the center of your clock is `(x_c, y_c)` and the radius of your clock is `r`.

Comment: He already solved this problem by switching the `sin` and `cos` with each other.